# Building Custom Drupal Form

Tags: 7, forms

I am trying to display a custom form with Drupal 7.

Here is what I am trying:

```
function mymodule_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['pay-online'] = array(
    'title' => 'Pay Online',
    'description' => 'Pay Online',
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('mymodule_form_generate'),
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
  );

  return $items;
}


function mymodule_form_generate() {

  $form['first_name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => 'First Name',
    '#attributes' => array('placeholder' => 'First Name'), 
  );

// ... etc, more form code

return $form;
```

What I am getting on the screen is a form, but it is not a 'drupal' form. It's just an array of form fields. No form id, etc.

What do I have to do in Drupal 7 to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should replace

```
function mymodule_form_generate() {
  $form = array();
```

with

```
function mymodule_form_generate($form, &$form_state) {
```

I'm not sure if this fixes things for you, but that is the only thing I can see that is out of order.

Comment: Just did that... no change.

Comment: @Kevin If you just edited the code of a module that is enabled on a Drupal site, you probably would not see any change. The fact the code is setting `$form` to an empty array is surely the cause the form doesn't contain what you would expect to find.

Answer (score -1):

You should use `return system_settings_form($form)`.

See [system_settings_form()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.module/function/system_settings_form/7), and what googletorp reported.

Comment: Why? Its not a system form, its a public front-end form. That function would save values to variables.

Comment: `system_settings_form()` is not only used for system forms, but it doesn't automatically suit every form; if I don't want to save the form field values in Drupal variables, I should not use that function.

Comment: You're right but this part is interesting: $form['#theme'] = 'system_settings_form'; See http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.module/function/theme_system_settings_form/7 It does a drupal_render_children which adds the id stuff